# wxpython, dc.GetAsBitmap returns an invalid bitmap

Tags: wxpython, bitmap

I am trying to get a bitmap of what my dc draws, but when I convert it to Image I get

```
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_gdi.py", line 618, in ConvertToImage
    return _gdi_.Bitmap_ConvertToImage(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "bmp.Ok()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dib.cpp(148) in wxDIB::Create(): wxDIB::Create(): invalid bitmap
```

It also gives the same error when trying to draw said bitmap to another dc. So I remember reading around here about a way to store the drawings of a ClientDC into a MemoryDC to then clean the ClientDC and draw the contents of the MemoryDC back onto it. What's the way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)

memory = wx.MemoryDC()
memory.SelectObject(bitmap)
#set pen, do drawing.
memory.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

img = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
```