# Make executable python application

Tags: python, windows

I have create with wxpython flatmenu an application and i was using [GUi2EXE](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) to make my program executable and i take the follow error:

```
File "myflat.py", line 411, in
File "myflat.py", line 47, in init
File "myflat.py", line 262, in CreateMenu
File "FlatMenu.pyc", line 2301, in init
File "ArtManager.pyc", line 1617, in CreateGreyBitmap
File "wx_gdi.pyc", line 668, in SaveFile
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "bmp.Ok()" failed at
  ....\src\msw\dib.cpp(148) in wxDIB::Create(): wxDIB::Create(): invalid bitmap
```

I check the names of the icons i use, i search everything and i cant find what is going on can anyone help me please?

Comment: Along with the traceback, could you show the code that produced the assertion?  The lines around Line 262 of myflat would be a good starting point.

Comment: @TLSK, you have 0% acceptation rate. If you want to increase your chance of getting attention, please accept (check the mark) some of the previous valid answers to your questions as other people already asked you to do.

Comment: Artmanager code is [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@l@i@limousine-HEAD@ui@FlatMenu@FlatMenu.py/102/ArtManager.ArtManager/python)

Comment: I find something about my question but i cant understand [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188331/wxpython-dc-getasbitmap-returns-an-invalid-bitmap/9105304#9105304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I will just answer since I cant comment yet -.- Here is what I use:

First, download and install py2exe if you haven't already, preferably using easy_install (a script plugin for python that lets you download things and automatically install them to your python path), make a file in whatever directory you are keeping your project in called setup.py, and place in the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
     console = [
         {
             "script": "yourscipt.py",
             "icon_resources": [(1, "youricon.ico")]
         }
     ],
)
```

after that, open a command prompt window in the setup.py file's directory, and type:

```
setup.py py2exe install
```

that will then spit out loads of output as it compiles your script, sets the icon, and finds the needed libraries for it. After that all is done, you will have two folders, one named build, the other named dist. The only folder you need is dist, where you will find your executable.

I hope this helped!

Comment: I did it but when  it compiles an error stop the compiling and when i try to run the executable file in dist folder i take the folow error Runtime error R6034, An application has made an attempt to load C runtime ibrary incorrectly.

Comment: I would go then with what the debugger outputted and look up how to properly us C runtime libraries, I have little experience with C and its associated libraries sorry!